# Assigning individual View Models to Nested Views?

Tags: c#-4.0, mvvm-light, datacontext, wpf-4.0

I have a MainView which has an associated MainViewModel in my WPF application, assigned via its contructor.

> App > *start up uri* > MainWindow.xaml

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new MainViewModel();

        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
```

My MainView holds as many as four nested views or child views who are hidden and displayed based upon the button that has been clicked on the MainView. So we toggling the visibility property vi a binding which gets updated via command bindings assigned to each button on the MainView.

Each nested View does not have an associated ViewModel, all bindings found on child views find their information in the MainViewModel. So binding system ends waling up the UI tree of the app to find out that the parent 'MainView' has an associated ViewModel.

So overall there is 'ONE' -> ViewModel. This seems to work fine and but as expected this VM has gotten to big and needs re-factoring. It holds information that contextually it should not. But this is a proof concept application. So i decided to keep it simple and make sure it was do-able.

**PROBLEM:**

When i tried assigning a empty view with an empty view model I noticed binding errors in the output window and as expected weird and broken behaviour. Which makes no sense ... Is there a more clear and concise way of letting WPF know how to handle any bindings it finds in a nested view control? I thought if each view's constructor assigned itself a corresponding VM as shown above, then it should work as this logically makes sense. Unfortunately all buttons on the MainView stop working when the corresponding view it is designated to switch on and hide the others has an associated ViewModel. On some buttons it works and the others it does not? This is really weird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my answer above, the problem was that WPF binding system was struggling to to resolve bindings at run time. The main view has its associated view model instantiated and assigned via the Main View contructor and this pattern is repeated for all nested views that the MainView also houses.

By default, I tend to use the implied binding syntax which means that without explicitly specifiying a source the binding system will try to resolve the name you supply in the binding. So it's all implied and nothing is explicitly set!

Upgrading each nested view to have its own view model makes this auto discovery/resolution of bindings go a little crazy and I have not explicitly told the binding system where to find the property I am looking for hence the output window binding errors.

This leads to unexpected behaviour as the output window was telling that it was trying to resolve binding expressions in nested views --> viewmodels. When in actual fact that VM it is looking in, IS EMPTY!

So clearly the binding system is good when you do not explicitly set a source property inside the binding syntax. It is clever enough to find things on its own. In my case it needed some extra help, as it was unsure as to where to find things.

**SOLUTION:**

1. Remove the constructor declaration for the MainViewModel in the MainView constructor.
2. Scope in an xmlns for ViewModels namesapce into your MainView.xaml
3. Create a window resource inside the MainView .xaml
4. Give the resource a key.
5. Upgrade all your bindings in the MainView xaml file to include source property.
6. Give the source property a static resource binding that points to your ViewModel key value set up in step 4.
7. Only do step 6 for bindings who refer to the ViewModel that is associate with the MainView.
8. All nested views are to be left alone, they should handle their own bindingds in their own xaml files. The MainView simply instantiates them and places them onto the UI. For me this was the case, I did not have any more bindings concerning my nested views. All Bindings that lived on the MainView.xaml file referred to data in the MainViewModel.cs. This makes alot easier when viewing your problem.

For some reason the editor was being awkward so I chose to omit any sample code but the steps above are descriptive enough to follow the steps that I took. Above is what worked for me.

***ANOTHER WAY OF SUMMING UP THIS PROBLEM***

- Most books teach the shorter binding syntax
- What happens when more than one data context is available?
- How is the binding system supposed to know how to resolve your short hand binding expressions.